# Runtime object creation in java

Tags: java

Is it possible to have Java object dynamically? I am new in this language and curious too.

**Edit:** Apology, I think I posted the wrong word.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: As stated, the premise of this question seems to be incorrect. Objects do not exist at compile time. They are *only* created at runtime.

Comment: I think you either swapped the terms Runtime (when the program is _running_) vs. compile time (when you hit _build_ in your IDE) or have some huge misconception about what an object is.

Comment: you need to read Herbert Schildt's Java book : http://books.google.be/books/about/Java.html?id=C_l2R8ZSPMoC&redir_esc=y and since you have just started learning, dont get discouraged by downvotes this happens to all of us at some point. This is how SO welcomes you :)

Comment: i don't know exactly,but is the OP asking to change its properties at run-time?

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi edited my question. Sorry for typo.

Comment: @SaumyaTiwari You should read some books and google your problems.

Comment: [Refer this for your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868986/dynamically-create-an-object-in-java-from-a-class-name-and-set-class-fields-by-u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes reflection can provide dynamic object creation(on fly )

```
Class anonymous = Class.forName("CLass name");
anonymous.getInstance();
```

All objects are created at Runtime in java.

Comment: But all objects are created at runtime.

Comment: `new Object()` gives you an Object at runtime without reflection...

Comment: objects are created at run-time, are you trying to edit the properties using reflection?

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi but if we don't know the class type and other class info then for creating the object dynamically it helps.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari But we need to catch a lot of Exceptions and this is a rather advanced topic so looking at the OP, probably not what she wanted.

Comment: She* wanted. @AlexR. and i think the discussion is inappropriate as the OP is a newbie.(and you are talking about refection).

Comment: @AlexR I also think so.

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi added character and fixed typo in post ;)

Comment: how come this is the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 2):

**Objects in Java are only created at Runtime.**

Answer (score 1):

Compilation phase is to translate human readable language that you use to code to byte code , which is understood by Java Virtual Machine, there's no object notion there.

Objects are created runtime by Java Virtual Machine based on classes that you create as a programmer.

Start here:

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-classes-and-objects