# JbdcTemplate - PreparedStatements with Dynamic SQL Query

Tags: sql, db2, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I know `jdbcTemplate` can be used to create `PreparedStatements` if you set it up to do so:

i.e.

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
String sqlQuery = "Select * from table where column = ?";
String value = "value";
this.jbdcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new Object[] { value }, rs, rowNum -> {
  System.out.println(rs.getString("column"));
});
```

However, I have a query with many AND operators in the Where clause, and depending on some condition, a specific AND statement may or may not be added to the query string.

i.e.

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder("Select * from table where 1=1 "); //base query
if(someCondition)
   sqlQuery.append("And column1 = '" + value1 + "'");
if(someCondition2)
   sqlQuery.append("And column2 = '" + value2 + "'");
if(someCondition3)
   sqlQuery.append("And column3 = '" + value3 + "'");
//etc...
```

With this type of dynamic query, I am unable to know exactly how many values to place in the `new Object[] {}` field at compile time, because the `someCondition` fields are always changing at runtime.

Is there a way to write the `this.jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery.toString(), new Object[] {}...` to accommodate these dynamic AND statements?

Comment: Surely you can create the `Object[]` at runtime with the appropriate size. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for that advice! That really helped. Since you can't resize arrays in Java at runtime, I was able to come up with a pretty simple solution to dynamically initialize the `Object[]` with the appropriate size at runtime. I still have another issue I need to fix before I post my solution though

Comment: The issue is that one of the dynamic `AND` statements is written like so: `AND column1 IN ('x','y','z','etc..')`, where the values inside of the parentheses will also be dynamic at runtime.

 I can't write the preparedStatement like `AND column1 IN (?)` and then plug the comma separated string value (i.e. `String values = "x,y,z,etc...";`)  in because it will treat the comma separated string value as a string literal, which leads to errors. I'm in the process of fixing this issue and I'll come back when I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after taking into consideration what @mustaccio said in his comment to my original question. I also took part of the solution from [this stackoverflow question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/13868986) and used it in my own solution.

The main issue I was having was dynamically creating an `Object[]` array at runtime, since you can't dynamically add elements to an `Object[]` array. They must have a defined size when initialized.

First, I create an arraylist of strings called `queryArgs`. Every time one of the if conditions proves true and we add an `AND` statement to the query, I also add another line of code that adds the value to be plugged in the preparedStatement to the `queryArgs` arraylist. Once that's done, I create a new `Object[]` array whose size is initialized to the size of the `queryArgs` arraylist. Lastly, I loop through each element in the `Object[]` array, setting them equal to the values in `queryArgs`.

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

List<QueryResults> jdbcQuery(QueryParams queryParams) {
    /* base query */
    StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder("Select * from table where 1=1 ");
    /* stores the dynamic preparedStatement arguments */
    List<String> queryArgs = new ArrayList<>();

    if(someCondition){
       sqlQuery.append("And column1 = ? ");
       queryArgs.add(queryParams.value1);
    }
    if(someCondition2){
       sqlQuery.append("And column2 = ? ");
       queryArgs.add(queryParams.value2);
    }
    if(someCondition3){
       sqlQuery.append("And column3 = ? ");
        queryArgs.add(queryParams.value3);
    }
    //etc...

    /* this is the part I used from the above stackoverflow question */
    Object[] preparedStatementArgs = new Object[queryArgs.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < preparedStatementArgs.length; i++){
        preparedStatementArgs[i] = queryArgs.get(i);
    }

    /* Lastly, execute the query */
    return this.jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery.toString(),
    preparedStatementArgs, (rs, rowNum) -> {

        QueryResults result = new QueryResults();
        /* store the results of the query... */
    });
}
```

The outlier is that one of the dynamic `AND` statements above is written like this:

```
AND column4 IN ('x','y','z','etc..'‌​)
```

, where the values inside of the parentheses are also dynamic at runtime. My service receives a string value that looks like this:

```
String queryParams.value4 = "x,y,z,etc...";
```

I can't write the preparedStatement like this: `AND column4 IN (?)` and then simply plug in `queryParams.value4` because it will treat `queryParams.value4` as a string literal, which leads to errors.

To solve this issue, I create another arraylist of strings called `value4Array`. I loop through every character in `queryParams.value4`, and I check if the current character in the loop is equal to a comma, our delimiter. If it is, then I create a substring of all the characters leading up to that comma, and add that newly created string to `value4Array`.

The next step is to create the dynamic `AND column4 IN (?)` statement. I do this by looping through each string value in the `value4Array` arraylist we just created, and doing a `sql.append("?")`, based on how many strings are in `value4Array`. After this, the rest of the logic is the same as my solution above.

```
/* this function takes the comma delimited string literal (value4 : "x,y,z,etc...")
   and parses it into an array of strings. */
private List<String> parseValue4(String value4){
    int valueIndex= 0;
    List<String> value4Array = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < value4.length(); i++){
        if(value4.charAt(i) == ','){
            value4Array.add(value4.substring(valueIndex, i));
            valueIndex = i + 1;
        }
        else if(i == value4.length() - 1){
            value4Array.add(value4.substring(valueIndex, value4.length()));
        }
    }
    return value4Array;
}
if(someCondition4){
   List<String> value4Array = parseValue4(queryParams.value4);
   sqlQuery.append("And column4 IN ("); /* base AND statement */
    for(int i = 0; i < value4Array.size(); i++){
        if(i == value4Array.size() - 1)
            sqlQuery.append("?)");
        else                       /* dynamically appending ?'s */
            sqlQuery.append("?,");
        queryArgs.add(value4Array.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: ...I would not be surprised if there is a library for this, which might make things easier for you, but don't know of any offhand.  `ArrayList` _does_ have a [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()) method, which should simplify that part of the code.  For dealing with the `IN` parameter, the `String` methods `split` and `join` will be helpful, as will `ArrayList`'s `addAll`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I wasn't sure how to make use of the `ArrayList` `addAll` method or the `String` `join` methods in this situation. 

I did however, remove the `Object[]` logic all together by using `toArray()` as you suggested on the `List<String> queryArgs` arrayList.

I also made good use of the `split` method instead of writing that unnecessary `parseValue4` function for creating the array of values since there's no point reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking list of string type `(List<String> queryArgs = new ArrayList<>();)`.
What if the parameter is an integer type? Is there any way to store multiple typle of data?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).