# Automatic conversion of form String input values to other java types dynamically to generate a class instance

Tags: java, generics, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a form which is accepting only `String` variables but I want to generate a `Class` instance such that **each string property is converted to its corresponding type identified by property name in the class**.

For e.g. If I have three fields in a form with the name of `NAME`, `ANNUAL SALARY` and `isLocalResident`. I want to convert this form to an instance of `Class1` where these properties are of `String`, `BigInteger` and `Boolean` type.

How do I do that?

Currently I am using `BeanUtil` Property of java, but it doesn't fulfill my requirement because it just doesn't covert to its required types; rather it asks me a setter and getter of the desired type.
Please help me out of this. Any suggestion would be appreciated?

**P note that this form is dynamic, i.e. number and name of fields shall depend on another input.** 
The following code represents generating instance `emp1` for `Employee1` class.

```
public Empolyee1 setContent(List<String> nameList, List<String> valueList) {
    Empolyee1 emp1 = new Empolyee1();

    for(String attr : nameList) {
        if(attr.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) { 
            if(valueList.get(nameList.indexOf("name")) != null && !valueList.get(nameList.indexOf("name")).trim().equals("")) {
                emp1.setName(valueList.get(nameList.indexOf("name")));
            }
    } else {
        if(attr.equalsIgnoreCase("ANNUAL SALARY")) {
            if(valueList.get(nameList.indexOf("ANNUAL SALARY")) != null && !valueList.get(nameList.indexOf("ANNUAL SALARY")).trim().equals("")) {
                  emp1.setAnnualSalary(valueList.get(nameList.indexOf("ANNUAL SALARY")));
            }
        } else {
            if(attr.equalsIgnoreCase("isLocalResident")) {
                if(valueList.get(nameList.indexOf("isLocalResident")) != null && !valueList.get(nameList.indexOf("isLocalResident")).trim().equals("")) {
                    emp1.setIsLocalResident(valueList.get(nameList.indexOf("isLocalResident")));    
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    return empl1;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear: you want to instance a class with a dynamic number of attributes (of a dynamic type) automatically converted ? You don't know the number and type of the attributes, but do you know the overall number and type of attributes ? Do you know the (for example) 50 possible attributes, that in the form could combine in every permutation ?

Comment: Refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868986/dynamically-create-an-object-in-java-from-a-class-name-and-set-class-fields-by-u

Comment: @AndreaLigios , Yes I know the overall number and type of attributes.  For example, I have 10 different classes with total number of 100 attributes. And each class may have different number of attributes. And i have xsd for each of the 10 classes containing getter and setter. Now, i have to set a class selected from UI.

Comment: Note that using a for each loop and `indexOf` isn't a good way of doing this: use a regular for loop with an int index (e.g. `i`), and use this to get corresponding elements of `nameList` and `valueList` (e.g. `String attr = nameList.get(i); String value = valueList.get(i).trim();`). Of course, using a `Map` would be better again...

Comment: Why not struts or spring?

Answer (score 0):

The key point is converting field name to Java Bean property name. `toPropertyName` method is a simple implementation based on the example of your question. (Bewared! if you need to support nested bean property, make sure your code prevent the potential class loader vulnerability of [CVE-2014-0114](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-0114/)...)

```
public static String toPropertyName(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    boolean toUpper = false;
    boolean isLower = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                sb.append((toUpper || isLower)?ch:Character.toLowerCase(ch));
                isLower = false;
            } else {
                isLower = true;
                sb.append(toUpper?Character.toUpperCase(ch):ch);
            }
            toUpper = false;
        } else {
            isLower = false;
            toUpper = true;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public Empolyee1 setContent(List<String> nameList, List<String> valueList) throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Iterator<String> nameIter = nameList.iterator();
    Iterator<String> valueIter = valueList.iterator();
    while (nameIter.hasNext()) {
        String name = (String) nameIter.next();
        map.put(toPropertyName(name), valueIter.hasNext()?valueIter.next():null);
    }
    Empolyee1 emp1= new Empolyee1();
    BeanUtils.populate(emp1, map);
    return emp1;
}
```

`BeanUtils.populate(emp1, map)` API is used to take other job. It convert inputed values and call setter of each Java Bean property.