# How to make ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor work even when all value is stored in string?

Tags: apache, apache-commons-lang3

How to make ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor work even
when a value is stored in a string?

here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String type     = "java.lang.Character";
        //char value     = 'c';  //this work
        String value = "c"; // this not work,throws[java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible constructor on object: java.lang.Character]
        Class<?> clazz  = ClassUtils.getClass(type);
        Object instance = ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor(clazz, value);
        System.out.println(instance);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException
            | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor(clazz, value);` this expression tries to invoke a construction on the `clazz` class with the argument `value`.

`java.lang.Character` only has the following constructor that accepts a character as the argument,

```
public Character(char value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

It does not have a construction that can accept a `String` argument, so when you invoke `ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor(clazz, value);`, it throws `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` and says `No such accessible constructor on object: java.lang.Character`.

To create a String class instance, you have to apply it on `java.lang.String`. Change `String type = "java.lang.Character";` to `String type = "java.lang.String";`

Comment: I found answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868986/dynamically-create-an-object-in-java-from-a-class-name-and-set-class-fields-by-u ,and must convert type manually very thanks!